# require() syntax in solidity for 0.5.0

Tags: blockchain, solidity

When I coded `require()` in solidity it is showing an error stating that to include error - reason in the `require()`. What is the correct syntax of require in solidity 0.5.0

I tried including error - reason inside and outside of require none of them worked

> error-reason: Provide an error message for require().

Comment: It's just the second parameter: `require(msg.value > 0, "You must send some ether!");`

Comment: try this require(msg.sender==owner):

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's not a compiler error. The message seems to belong `ethlint` library. https://github.com/duaraghav8/Ethlint

However, it's a good practice to include error messages to `require` statements:

Example: `require(i % 2 == 0, "It should be an even number");`